# Collections.binarySearch(List list, K key) clarification. Java

Tags: java, return, binary-search

Given the following statement, taken from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/algorithms/index.html#shuffling) Oracle java tutorial, related to the binarySearch() method of the class Collections:

> The return value is the same for both forms. If the List contains the
>   search key, its index is returned. If not, the return value is
>   **(-(insertion point) - 1)**, where the insertion point is the point at
>   which the value would be inserted into the List, or the index of the
>   first element greater than the value or list.size() if all elements in
>   the List are less than the specified value.

Why does the return value of `binarySearch()` not return only the negative index instead of the negative index minus 1? (the part in bold of the quote above mentioned).

In brief: why `(-(insertion point) - 1)` and not only `(-(insertion point))`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because if it is not in the list but should be on position `0`, how would that be displayed otherwise?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's because `-(insertion point)` would be ambiguous. You wouldn't be able to tell the following apart:

- item found at position `0`;
- item not found, and insertion point is `0`.

With `-(insertion point) - 1`, the above two cases result in different return values (`0` and `-1`).

Answer (score 7):

from your link

> This admittedly ugly formula guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the search key is found. It's basically a hack to combine a boolean (found) and an integer (index) into a single int return value